# В чём разница при использовании new Srtring("") и простого присваивания?

Tags: java, строки

В чём разница при использовании new Srtring("") и простого присваивания?

Comment: компилятор за вас пропишет `=new String("")`

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat 
это не так 
смотри код:

     public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  String s1 = "";
  String s2 = new String("");

  String s3 = "";
  String s4 = "";

  String s5 = new String("");
  String s6 = new String("");

  System.out.println(s1 == s2);
  System.out.println(s3 == s4);
  System.out.println(s5 == s6);
 }

и результат:

false
true
false

Comment: @zamutil http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning
"All compile-time constant strings in Java are automatically interned using this method"

Comment: А можно включить интернирование строк и тогда вполне может быть, что все варианты выведут true. В целом, сравнивать строки с помощью `==` - плохая затея, если не понимать, что там твориться.

Comment: У меня был похожий вопрос недавно. Но хотя не совсем отвечает наш вопрос, но некоторые нюансы можно узнать отсюда: http://hashcode.ru/questions/311521/java-string-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[@zamutil](/users/18382/zamutil) как верно подметил  [@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)

> плохая затея, если не понимать, что
> там твориться.

так как ссылкам s1,s3,s4 присваивается одна и та же строка а именно (**`""`**) то компилятор создаёт один объект! с текстом (**`""`**) и ссылку на него записывает в s1,s3,s4.

главное помнить что при (a==b) сравниваются ссылки а в (a.equals(b)) сравнивается содержимое

Comment: я про иквелс знаю  
просто я в интернете наткнулся на этот пример, и написано что это связано со строковым пулом и ссылка на эту статью http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3

с английским туго, вот думал может кто объяснить на "пальцах"

Comment: В java строки неизменяемые. А это значит, что компилятор может собрать все видимые ему строки и исключить дубликаты. Это может очень позитивно сказаться на потребляемой памяти. Более того, виртуальная машина умеет в процессе работы брать эти готовые строки. То есть, при *некоторых настройках*, если при конкатенации строк получается новая, которая есть в пуле, ее и будут использовать. Это конечно вредит производительности, но экономит память. Зато дает возможность сравнивать строки через обычное `==`, что может сильно ускорить.

На почитать - http://habrahabr.ru/post/79913/

Comment: Мне кажется, что половина ответа вообще не по теме вопроса. "плохая затея, если не понимать, что там твориться", "главное помнить что при (a==b) сравниваются ссылки а в (a.equals(b)) сравнивается содержимое". Вопрос был "в чём разница между `new String()` и просто присваивания. А то что по теме - очень сжато. И не особо ясно, ИМХО.

Answer (score 2):

#### В чём разница между двумя подходами?

- При простом присваивании строка будет помещаться в *string pool*. Кратко: если вы создадите ещё одну точно такую же строку, то она лишь сошлётся на уже существующую в `string pool`'е, а не будет создаваться заново. Но если вы пропишите `new String(...)` строка в *string pool* **не попадёт**.
- Простое присваивание короче. И это сделано не случайно: строки создаются очень часто.
- Когда вы используете просто присваивание, вы не можете указать доп. параметров (кодировку например). Вы указываете только саму строку. Конструкторы же дают в этом плане больше возможностей.

#### Когда стоит использовать `new String`?

- Когда вы хотите не просто создать строку, а например указать какие-то дополнительные параметры или преобразовать строку из массива `byte[]`/ `char[]`. В классе `String` более 10 конструкторов, и это не просто так.

Пример из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

```java
char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
String str = new String(data);
```

#### Когда использовать просто присваивание?

- Когда вам нет смысла использовать конструкторы. В таком случае вы сэкономите память (благодаря `string pool`'у) и код будет не такой громоздкий (присваивание просто короче).

#### Ссылки

- Про *string pool* - [В java строка примитив или объект?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1137061/%d0%92-java-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82/1137067#1137067) - ответ `@Sergei Buvaka`.

Comment: Написал свой ответ, так как считаю, что в принятом ответе тема практически не раскрыта (ИМХО, по теме там лишь 2 строчки)