# В java строка примитив или объект?

Tags: java, строки, ооп, объекты, примитивы

Допустим, я создаю строку, присваивая её переменной A. Вопрос, в A хранится ссылка на эту строку или её значение. Если я присвою строковой переменной B значение A и изменю значение В, будет ли изменено значение А?

Бонусный вопрос. В чём различие этого:

```
String a = "hi!";
```

От этого:

```
String a = new String("hi!");
```

Надеюсь на обстоятельный ответ, так как только начал изучать java.

Comment: "Если я присвою строковой переменной B значение A и изменю значение В, будет ли изменено значение А?" - сколько нужно времени, чтобы это выяснить?

Comment: Я мыслил в точности, как и вы и, конечно, проверил. Это мне дало весьма противоречивый ответ, так как значение А не изменилось, что должно было бы говорить о том, что строки - примитивы. Но я всё же склоняюсь к тому, что это объекты. Это разногласие и побудило попросить совет у более квалифицированных коллег.

Comment: В Java строки это immutable object, и они являются оберткой над массивом чаров

Comment: @Mr.Kapitoshka строки - это объекты. Но неизменяемые (если не учитывать рефлексию)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java строка является ссылочным типом данных. Но с оговоркой, что под капотом есть некая оптимизация которая называется String Pool. Это сделано потому что строки в Java используются очень часто.

**Что такое String Pool?** Всякий раз когда вы создаёте строку таким образом

```
String text = "Hello";
```

Компилятор проверяет создавалась ли ранее такая строка? Если такая строка уже есть, то вы просто получаете на нее ссылку. Если нет, то строка добавляется в пул.

```
String text = new String ("Hello");
```

Создание строки таким образом ничем не отличается от прошлого варианта, за исключением того, что строка "Hello" будет добавлена в пул в любом случае, независимом от того есть ли она уже там или нет.

Из этого есть некий вывод:

```
String text = "Hello";
String text2 = "Hello";

text == text2 - true т.к. ссылки будут одинаковые.

String text = new String ("Hello");
String text2 = new String ("Hello");

text == text2 - false т.к. ссылки будут ссылаться на разные ячейки в памяти
```

Comment: Спасибо, поправил

Comment: Стринги это объекты

Answer (score 2):

Отвечу сразу на бонусный вопрос!) 
в первом случае новый объект может и не создаться, а вытянуться из пула констант а во втором случае принудительное создание нового объекта. То есть:

```
String a = "a";
String b = "a";

a == b // true

String a = new String("a");
String b = new String("a");

a == b // false
```

Строки в Java это обертка над `byte[] value`, что можно увидеть перейдя в класс `String.class`

```
String a = "f"; //Проверяется пулл констант, создается новый объект, ссылка на объект сохраняется в переменную a
String b = "f"; //Проверяется пулл констант, берется ссылка на уже созданный объект и сохраняется в переменную b
String c = new String("f"); // Создается новый объект
String d = a; //Ссылка на объект из одного чара "f" дублируется в переменную d
d = "g";
b = "l";
System.out.println(a); // f
System.out.println(b); // l
System.out.println(c); // f
System.out.println(d); // g
```

Comment: И всё же. Можно ли вас просить дать мне ответ на основной вопрос?